# What is benefit of service logic testing and client logic testing in WCF web services testing?

Tags: wcf, testing, nunit, automated-tests

I Develop WCF web services for  enterprise project.I use NUnit testing in service logic business layer for test in server side and in client side I use WCFTestClient for invoke web services  method.
I have to do automated test for my project,But I really don't know which approach is better?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you both. Service Logic testing is important from the perspective of the service as is, it must works just as expected and that's what you test.

Now, Client testing is also important from the perspective (as it names implies) of service clients. I mean, client testing helps you in the design of clear and usable service APIs. When you test what your service users will be doing you get another perspective of the situation.